# Biblatex with apa6 package on Ubuntu

Tags: biblatex, texlive, apa-style, ubuntu, apa6

I am trying to get the [`apa6`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apa6) package to work on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). In order to do so, I first installed TeX Live2012 from [`texlive-backports`](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa), and after some trying installed the following packages:

```
#install fonts
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra

#install apa6/biblatex stuff
sudo apt-get install biblatex biblatex-dw
sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers
```

The [sample document](http://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/apa6/samples/shortsample.tex) that is included in the `apa6` package now almost compiles, the only thing that is not working is the citations. At every occurrence of `\textcite` or `\parencite`, it throws an error:

```
There are several problems at this line:
  -'\parencite' not defined by citation style.
  -Package biblatex Error: Command '\cite' undefined. A three-author paper \parencite
```

See also this screenshot (click to enlarge):

[image]

Am I missing some dependency?

Comment: Doesn't `apa6` rely on its own BibTeX(!) `apacite` package for citations/bibliography?

Comment: That's a typical set of errors to get if you press on with typesetting a file where you have tried to load a biblatex style that does not exist. Without seeing logs I couldn't be sure, but I think you are probably missing the biblatex-apa files, which are in the biblatex-apa package. Check the logs and try kpsewhich apa.bbx.

Comment: @jon Whether it does or not, I don't think that's the problem here. The OP's source if correctly set up for `biblatex`, which is complaining in a way that suggests it hasn't been fed files it needs.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you all for the comments. I solved the problem by installing the Ubuntu/Debian package `texlive-bibtex-extra`.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
sudo texhash
```

After this the sample document compiled just fine. I did not have to edit the document at all. I suppose it has to do with the ctan packages 'biblatex' and 'biblatex-apa' which are part of this package.

In retrospect I should probably have been able to figure this out myself, although I am not quite sure what the reasoning of the texlive maintainers is to break it up like this... I would assume that both the `texlive-publishers` and `biblatex` Debian packages would take care the of required biblatex dependencies.

Comment: You miss one point: There is no need to use apa6 with biblatex. So there is no dependency. The dependency comes from using them together in the example document. But this is not a dependency that is strict. If you read the documentation of apa6, you see that you can use natbib, apacite, or biblatex styles. There is *NO* way that all possible combinations will ever by automatically be possible, unless we package all of TeX Live into *ONE* package of 2Gb (and we have already people complaining about the size of some of the smaller packages ;-)